# Override bootstrap !important

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to get rid of outline in my dropdown list when focus state. See this image

[image]

I tried to override bootstrap using !important but not working at all. Just check the dev tools and suddenly see this.

[image]

Bootstrap is also using !important tag. So I couldn't override it. I can use id to button and set focus outline to 0 but I have so many dropdowns in my website. Any fix for this kind of situation?

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus{
   outline: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `style.css` file loads before your Bootstrap css file. However, you have to load your `style.css` after the `bootstrap-select.min.css` file in order to override the Bootstrap styles.

[image: CSS file priority]

Comment: I’m happy to help

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML, load `style.css` after you have loaded `bootstrap-select.min.css`.

In other words, load `bootstrap-select.min.css` first, then load `style.css`.

Within the same rule, the property that got defined later on will override the formerly defined property.

Comment: It is not true that this always work. I am having a similar problem with overriding bootstrap classes, and my stylesheet loads after the bootstrap cdn. Still doesn't work.

Comment: In some cases like different selector, stylesheet that is loaded later might still get overridden by selector of higher specificity. See [Specificity - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).